# I once gave my Ethernet a static IP-address but now it changes to it automatically all the time?

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, ipv4

My question is about the error inside my Ethernet Adapter inside the Ipv4 protocol.
I screwed things up inside the registers, I guess. 
How to fix it that it never gives it a static IP address again?
It now always changes to `192.168.25.1`, because I set it up like that in the past.

[image: My current situation]

Comment: Please clarify (edit) your question. The title says the opposite of the text of the question. I can't tell from this if you want to put it back to automatic or if you want to fix the incomplete static configuration.

Comment: If you don't want a static IP address why don't you choose the "automatically assign" an address option?

Comment: Everytime when I change it to automatically assing it changes it back to static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you changed in the registry, but you can try this and it will hopefully be of some help.

First open the run box by hitting `Windows key + R` and then type `regedit` to open the registry.

Then navigate to the correct network adapter by going to the registry location `MyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`

Each network adapter will have a different hex subkey that looks like this. [Registry hex subkeys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTsWN.jpg)

From this point on, I don't know what DWORDS and string values you have.

Check to see if you have a DWORD (blue icons) that is called `EnableDHCP`. If you do, check and make sure that the hex value is `1`. If it has a value `0`, change it to `1` and restart your PC.

You could also put a screenshot of what your registry values look like for the network interface. It may make it easier to see what is wrong.